# Pass method as a parameter on python

Tags: python, class, methods

Can I pass a method as a parameter on python? 
I want to do things like, for example, if anything is an instance of an object w/has foo method:

`def access_to(class=anything, method="foo"):
     return class.method`

(Note is obvious that Anything instance doesn't have the attribute 'method', and Ill get an AttributeError).

Comment: I dont want to call a function as a method of the class object, the function I wanna make is outside that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uses getattr if you want to get the method from a string parameter.

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

def access_to(c, method="foo"):
     return getattr(c, method)

a = A()
b = 5
access_to(a)()
access_to(b)()
```

It prints foo for a, then it raises error for b

I have to say that I recommend not to abuse this type of functions unless you have to for some specific reasons.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks u! (ps: its a very particular case, ive to handle with too large named methods (i didnt built that) and ive to call a function which uses these methods too much time. Thanks u)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can pass a method as a parameter to a function in Python. In my example below, I created a class (`MyClass`) which has two methods: `isOdd` and `filterArray`. I also created an `isEven` function outside of `MyClass`. The `filterArray`
takes two parameters - an array and a function that returns `True` or `False` - and uses the method passed as a parameter to filter the array.

Additionally, you can pass lambda functions as parameter, which is like creating a function on the fly without having to write a function declaration.

```
def isEven(num):
    return num % 2 == 0

class MyClass:

    def isOdd(self, num):
        return not isEven(num)

    def filterArray(self, arr, method):
        return [item for item in arr if method(item)]

myArr = list(range(10))  # [0, 1, 2, ... 9]

myClass = MyClass()

print(myClass.filterArray(myArr, isEven))
print(myClass.filterArray(myArr, myClass.isOdd))
print(myClass.filterArray(myArr, lambda x: x % 3 == 0))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```